# Attain matrix transpose by row swaps and column swaps

Tags: matrices

Given a matrix and the two operations row swap and column swap, how to prove the possibility or impossibility of getting the transpose via a composition of these operations?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Right, I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: If $a$ and $b$ are in the same row of a matrix, can a row swap or a column swap put them into different rows of the new matrix?